# Mocking / stubbing mongoose findById with sinon

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to stub my mongoose model, specifically the `findById` method of mongoose

I'm trying to make mongoose return the specified data, when findById is called with 'abc123'

Here's what I have so far:

```
require('../../model/account');

sinon = require('sinon'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
accountStub = sinon.stub(mongoose.model('Account').prototype, 'findById');
controller = require('../../controllers/account');

describe('Account Controller', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        accountStub.withArgs('abc123')
            .returns({'_id': 'abc123', 'name': 'Account Name'});
    });

    describe('account id supplied in querystring', function(){
        it('should retrieve acconunt and return to view', function(){
            var req = {query: {accountId: 'abc123'}};
            var res = {render: function(){}};

            controller.index(req, res);
                //asserts would go here
            });
    });
```

My problem is that I am getting the following exception when running mocha

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property findById as function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose). You can expects chained methods with just a few lines:

```
// If you are using callbacks, use yields so your callback will be called
sinon.mock(YourModel)
  .expects('findById').withArgs('abc123')
  .chain('exec')
  .yields(someError, someResult);

// If you are using Promises, use 'resolves' (using sinon-as-promised npm) 
sinon.mock(YourModel)
  .expects('findById').withArgs('abc123')
  .chain('exec')
  .resolves(someResult);
```

You can find working examples on the repo.

Also, a recommendation: use `mock` method instead of `stub`, that will check the method really exists.

Comment: Possible to add more to the example showing how to get back mocked data? Answer seems incomplete as far as what user is asking for.

Comment: @lostintranslation the mocked data would be the "someResult" argument on "yield" and "resolves".

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are testing a single class, I'd roll with the generic

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var accountStub = sinon.stub(mongoose.Model, 'findById');
```

This will stub any calls to `Model.findById` patched [by mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById).